recursive function problem using stack: Can't expand stack segment by 12 bytes to 524288 bytes. Use -lstack # with # > 524288
I'm trying to tanslate a c code to a mips assembly code but when i use stack in the recursive function, qtspim shows this error:

Can't expand stack segment by 12 bytes to 524288 bytes.
Use -lstack # with # > 524288

this this the code in c that I'm trying to translate into mips assembly code:
#include <stdio.h>
Int fibonacci(int n)
{

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    else
        return (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2));
}
int main()
{
    int nbr, i = 0, j;
    printf("Enter the number of terms \n");
    scanf("%d", &nbr);
    printf("The first %d terms of the Fibonacci series are:\n", nbr);
    for (j = 1; j <= nbr; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", fibonacci(i));
        i++;
    }
    return 0;

}

and that's my mips code:
.data
n: .word 0
i: .word 0
k: .word 0
msg1: .asciiz "Enter the number of terms\n"
msg2: .asciiz "The first "
msg3: .asciiz " terms of Fibonacci series are:\n"
msg4: .asciiz "\n"

.text
main:

li $v0, 4          #print msg1
la $a0, msg1       #load msg1 to print
syscall 
li $v0, 5          #scan n
syscall
move $s0, $v0      #save n in $s0
sw $s0, n($0)      #save n in memory
li $v0, 4          #print msg2
la $a0, msg2       #load msg2 to print
syscall 
li $v0,1           # print n
move $a0, $s0      # Load n to print
syscall
li $v0,4           #print msg3
la $a0, msg3       #load msg3 to print
syscall 
li $t0, 1          #the begining of k
li $t1, 0          #the begining of i
loop:
bgt $t0, $s0, exit #if k>n go to "exit"
jal fib            #function call
move $a0, $v0      #print result
li $v0, 1
syscall
la $a0, msg4       #print msg4
li $v0, 4
syscall
add $t1, $t1, 1    #i++
add $t0, $t0, 1    #k++
j loop
exit:  
li $v0,10          # exit
syscall


fib:
  
    bne $a0, 1, else     # if n != 1, go to else
    move $v0, $a0        # move n to the function's argument
    jr $ra               # return n

else:
    # Allocate stack frame
    sub $sp, $sp, 12     # allocate 12 bytes on the stack (4 bytes for each saved register)
    sw $ra, 0($sp)       # save the return address
    sw $a0, 4($sp)       # save n (function argument)
    
    # Calculate fib(n-1)
    add $a0, $a0, -1     # n - 1
    jal fib              # recursive call to fib(n - 1)
    lw $a0, 4($sp)       # restore n (function argument)
    sw $v0, 8($sp)       # save return value of fib(n - 1)
    
    # Calculate fib(n-2)
    add $a0, $a0, -2     # n - 2
    jal fib              # recursive call to fib(n - 2)
    lw $t0, 8($sp)       # restore return value of fib(n - 1)
    
    # Calculate fib(n) as fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    add $v0, $t0, $v0    # add fib(n-1) and fib(n-2)
    
    # Restore saved registers and stack frame
    lw $ra, 0($sp)       # restore the return address
    add $sp, $sp, 12     # deallocate stack frame
    
    jr $ra               # return the result

I'm new at programming

Step through the program. Look at what is in $a0 (n) at the very first call to fib. Also look at $t0 in the main program after fib returns.
